# SELENIUM WEB DRIVER - Click in a Filter

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I'm doing a `Selenium Webdriver` to automatize a system to my company.

I have to click in a filter which name is `Alunos - Ativos nos últimos 30D`.

It worked when I run for the first time but now I have the error:

```
ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (404, 597)
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.212)
```

My code:

```
filtro_30D = nav.find_element_by_xpath ('//span[@title="Alunos - Ativos nos últimos 30D"]')

time.sleep(10)

filtro_30D.click()
```

HTML from the button:

```
<span class="sage-dropdown__item-label" title="Alunos - Ativos nos últimos 30D">Alunos - Ativos nos últimos 30D</span>
```

Could someone help me please?

Comment: `Message: element click intercepted` -- this means there is some element on top of your targeted element that receives the click instead. Unless you can share your website, you will probably have to figure out what is intercepting the click and how to avoid it.

Comment: did you run it with window (not `headless`) to see what you have in browser? Maybe it has some popup message and it may need to click some button to close it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to click using JavaScript executor like this:

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()",filtro_30D)
```

This will execute this javascript code and will click on that filter. It usually works when selenium.click() fails.